# 3 Level Queries in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015

Workitems have the following hierarchy in my tfs project.
Features -> Product Backlog -> Tasks.

I want to write 1 query which shows all features, all product backlogs under the feature & then all tasks under the product backlog. Is there a way I can do it ?

This is what I came up with right now, it shows me only Features->ProductBacklogs (2 levels) but not the tasks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To create the grandparent-child you described simply pick "Tree of work items" and set the top level to have **Work Item Type = Feature** and the lower ("linked") level to have **Work Item Type = Task**.

See attached image.
[azure devops screenshot - grandparent-child query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbY0a.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change "Work Items and Direct Links" to "Tree of Work Items" to get multiple levels of work items.

Comment: The Tree of Work Items too give me only 2 levels . Feature & Product Backlog. Doesn't give me the tasks under a product backlog. Let me know if I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: I no long have the query which does exactly what I want in front of me to double check the settings, but it certainly does work. I would start by checking that at least one Product Backlog has a *child* task.

Comment: so correction :tree of work items gives me all the children but does not give me any work items that are related.

Comment: Correct, to only shows Parent/Child relationships. Task is a child of PBI, PBI is a child of Feature. Related links are just FYI and not part of the flow of executable items.